# Can someone explain this for loop in C? for(x = i = 0; i <= 100; i += 2, x += i);

Tags: c, for-loop

```
for(x = i = 0; i <= 100; i += 2, x += i);
```

Why does the code above add to x all even numbers added together from 0 to 102, inclusive as opposed to the code beneath that stores in x all even numbers added together from 0 to 100, inclusive?

```
for(x = i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
    if (!(i % 2))
         continue;
    x = x + i;
}
```

Comment: The first loop shown does not print any numbers.

Comment: What’s the point of writing or critiquing superfluously-over-obfuscated code. Doing that is as eeezy as garbling gobbledy gook. Just write it simple.

Comment: You probably wanted `for(x = i = 0; i <= 100; x += i,  i += 2);` as the equivalent of the second loop.

Comment: The second snippet adds the **odd** numbers from 1 to 99.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I didn't mean to write that it prints the numbers as well.   It's something that I have to understand for my programming class, so I wanted to get a solid idea of exactly how its works

Answer (score 2):

If it makes it clearer, the first snippet can be translated exactly as this:

```c
i = 0;
x = 0;
while (i <= 100)
{
  i +=2;
  x += i; //sum of the even numbers from 2 to 102 inclusive
}
```

And the second one as this:

```c
i = 0;
x = 0;
while (i <= 100)
{
  if (!(i % 2)) continue; //skip even numbers
  x += i; //sum of the odd numbers from 1 to 100
  i++; 
}
```

Comment: Yay for simplicity and clarity. +1. It should have been written like this by the original author - even if your version may be not quite the same as the original. It’s the difficulty of understandIng what the original (and other 3*-style/cram-it-all-into-one-line code) does that makes it so toxic.